# How to open a file with running instance of netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, single-instance

When I run the following command it opens a new instance everytime. Is it possible to open file in the running instance of netbeans ?

I'm using NetbeansPortable 8.2

```
E:/Netbeans/NetBeansPHPPortable.exe --open "c:\\test.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

> If there is an instance of the IDE already running, the file will
>   simply open in this instance and the command will exit. You may need
>   to pass the --userdir option to match the user directory of the
>   running IDE.

Source: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCliOpen